# verification mail link not working

Tags: tokens, emails, authentication-authorization

I have the following issue:
When a user register to the site he receives a message with a unique url in order to activate his account. so far so good. However when the user clicks the link provided instead of the normal page it redirects to http://example.com/user/%5Buser%3Aoriginal%3Auid%5D/view
If the user copies the link from the email in the url bar then the page loads correctly. I tried all the tokens available but the problem remains.Where should I search?

Comment: URL shared above has token "[user:original:uid]" as it is - not its replaced value, you need try to using different token, also check the link text if that works correctly.

Comment: I tried also [user:one-time-login-url] and [user:validation-url] but still same thing happens... In case I copy paste the link or I open new tab with right click it works normally...I suspect mayve it has to do with clean urls or pathauto?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share a screenshot of < a > tag or entire tag here for more detail?

Comment: I just figured out that maybe there is an issue with the email clients. E.g. from outlook express it is working normally, however when I  try to click it from a webmail it does that strange behaviour.. <a> tag  you mean the link from the email?

Comment: Ok, great. Yes < a > tag i mean link in email.